# Hyperlinks to phone numbers where the business/person's name show up on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I've seen this once on a web site, whereby, when I click the phone number link, the iPhone shows the name of the business at the top of the screen (As it would if I'd had them as a contact in my contact list).

If someone did it, I'd be surprised everyone wasn't doing it.  It'd make it much easier, when I go to look in my "recents" list or if I want to convert the called number into a contact, the name would already be there.

Was I dreaming? Was it a JavaScript trick? :-)

Comment: What website was it on? Can you look at the source? If it really is js, it should probably be available.

Comment: EmmyS here is one example http://www.instant-mex-auto-insur.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:18005551212">call 1 800 555 1212</a>
```

Only works with iphones.

```
<a href="callto://+***********">Link will initiate Skype to call my number!</a>
```

is used by skype.

People who browse using their iphones like and "normally" remember the link.